# unable to deploy .net project using TFS IIS app deployment task

Tags: tfs, iis-8

I am trying to deploy my project to IIS using TFS Winrm:IIS web app deployment task. I am new to this.

I am getting the following error'

"Deployment failed on machine xxx with following message : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server xxx failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". "

I was able deploy the project to the same remote server using TFS Winrm: windows machine file copy task which is the prior step for web app deployment to IIS. Winrm service is running and when it type the "winrm quickconfig i am getting "winrm is already been configured".

What am i missing here ? please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Winrm:IIS task is actually MSDeploy from Machine A to Machine B so for this to work you need to install MSDeploy on Machine B.  You should then be ok to deploy from Machine A.  Check [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppMgmt/IISWebAppMgmtV1/README_IISAppMgmt.md) article out for more information and to see if you have all the pre-requisite.  Also these articles have a bit more info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=azure-devops
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp

Comment: Sure.. i will check that. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved when i enable remote powershell remoting my remote machine using the command Enable-PSRemoting –force